# django when a new model field is added showing error

Tags: django

Previously the class is

```
class room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    r = models.IntegerField()
    c = models.IntegerField()    
    total = models.IntegerField()
    inv1 = models.CharField(max_length=60, default = 'None')
    inv2 = models.CharField(max_length=60, default = 'None')
    inv3 = models.CharField(max_length=60, default = 'None')
```

I added `t = models.IntegerField(default = 10)` to it. When migrate, it is showing the error

Running migrations:
  Applying allotment.0007_auto_20190316_2314...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 300, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 172, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 239, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py", line 790, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py", line 785, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py", line 1807, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

Comment: add full error traceback

Comment: Run `manage.py showmigrations` my guess is: you have added new field with a copy-pasted textual default `'None'`, created broken migration with this wrong default, then changed default to 10 and created another migration. Or this is not the full source. Error message is pretty clear - you cannot set textual default for numeric field. And, probably, you want `None` which means `NULL` instead of `'None'` which is a string of four letters and nothing else.

Comment: i removed the whole class but showing the same error. can u pls help me on this

Comment: Can you add the content of the migration file (the last one) which would be inside the migrations folder inside the app (allotment) folder?  The name maybe like allotment.0007_auto_20190316_2314. That fill will be having the code which is causing this error.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works well.